# Python- Square Root of list

Tags: python, list, square-root

Taking the square root of each number in a list.

For this problem in the sqrt_list function:

1. Take the square root of each item in the list,
2. Store each squared item in another list, and
3. Return this list.

```
alist = [11,22,33]
def sqrt_list(alist):
    ret = []
    for i in alist:
        ret.append(i %)
    return ret
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?

Comment: def sqrt_list(x):
    new_list=[]
    for item in y:
        y=item%
        new_list.append(y)
    return y
sqrt_list(list)

Comment: list(11,22,33)
def sqrt_list(list):
    ret = []
    for i in list:
        ret.append(i %)
    return ret

Comment: What is the issue with the code written so far? Please read the page I have linked, particularly the point about asking a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```py
# Use this import for all examples
from math import sqrt

old = [1,2]
new = [sqrt(x) for x in old]
```

---

Function form

```py
def sqrt_list(old):
    return [sqrt(x) for x in old]
```

or

```py
def sqrt_list(old):
    new_list = []

    for i in old:
        new_list.append(sqrt(i))

    return new_list
```

---

Where:

```py
print(sqrt_list([11, 22, 33]))
```

outputs:

```py
[3.3166247903554, 4.69041575982343, 5.744562646538029]
```

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you.

Comment: No worries, let me know if you have any issues

Comment: (old) = [11,22,33]

def sqrt_list(old):
    new_list = []

    for i in old:
        new_list.append(sqrt(i))

    return new_list

Comment: It is saying "NameError." Do I have to define what number I want in the list, like above?

Comment: did you copy and paste the function?

Comment: def sqrt_list(old):
    return [sqrt(x) for x in old]
print(sqrt_list([11, 22, 33]))

Comment: This seems to have returned the same output^

Comment: Is it working correctly ?

Comment: def sqrt_list(old):            
                  return [sqrt(x) for x in old]
                  print(sqrt_list([11, 22, 33])).        Yes, this one returns the correct output

Comment: No worries :), if this has solved the problem; please mark it as the accepted answer.